# TikZ: plot data files with spaces in path

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I tried to plot a data file with spaces is the file path.

```
\draw[line width=0.4mm] plot[] file{/home/schlumpf/test folder/daten.txt};
```

My problem is the space in the file path. How can I plot this file without copying the file to another folder?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is place the filename within double quotes. The command should now read

```
\draw[line width=0.4mm] plot[] file{"/home/schlumpf/test folder/daten.txt"};
```

This works any time (or almost) you use a filename in a TeX command. It is the same thing as when you are working in a command line environment (Unix shell commands for example).

To avoid this type of problem, many people will refrain from using spaces or exotic symbols within file or folder names.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. If I write the path in quotes, I get this warning and no plot: Plot data file `"/home/schlumpf/test folder/daten.txt"' not found. on input line 36.